# XSLT transformation of a XML file

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I have XML like this, i can have  Model with Region and TT and Model with only TT:

```
<Brand id="1" desc="IH">
    <Type id="1" desc="Tractors">
        <Product id="1" desc="Tractors">
            <Series id="10496" desc="MXC">
                <Model id="10497" desc="MX100C" tsCode="048">
                    <Region id="4" name="APAC" desc="Asia Pacific" />
                    <Region id="1" name="NA" desc="North America" />
                    <TT code="696033805" desc="-MX MAXXUM MFD  " colCode="2" />
                    <TT code="696033808" desc="-MX MAXXUM 100C " colCode="2" />
                    <TT code="696044567" desc="-MX MAXXUM 300C " colCode="2" />
                </Model>
                <Model id="11597" desc="abc123" tsCode="765">
                    <TT code="123033805" desc="-AX XERCES ABCD  " colCode="1" />
                    <TT code="234033808" desc="-AX XERCES EDF   " colCode="3" />
                </Model>
            </Series>
        </Product>
    </Type>
</Brand>
```

I need to obtain a csv like this:

```
brandid=1;TypeID=1;Productid=1;SeriesID=1;Modelid=10497;Regionid =4;TTcode=696033805
brandid=1;TypeID=1;Productid=1;SeriesID=1;Modelid=10497;Regionid =4;TTcode=696033808
brandid=1;TypeID=1;Productid=1;SeriesID=1;Modelid=10497;Regionid =4;TTcode=696044567
brandid=1;TypeID=1;Productid=1;SeriesID=1;Modelid=10497;Regionid =1;TTcode=696033805
brandid=1;TypeID=1;Productid=1;SeriesID=1;Modelid=10497;Regionid =1;TTcode=696033808
brandid=1;TypeID=1;Productid=1;SeriesID=1;Modelid=10497;Regionid =1;TTcode=696044567
brandid=1;TypeID=1;Productid=1;SeriesID=1;Modelid=10497;Regionid =1;TTcode=696033808
brandid=1;TypeID=1;Productid=1;SeriesID=1;Modelid=11597;Regionid = ;TTcode=123033805
brandid=1;TypeID=1;Productid=1;SeriesID=1;Modelid=11597;Regionid = ;TTcode=234033808
```

I have try this XSLT but is not correct the result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="ISO-8859-1" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space  elements="*"/>
<xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#x0A;'" />
<xsl:variable name="tab" select="'&#x09;'" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <!-- <xsl:apply-templates select="ProductList/Brand" /> -->
      <xsl:apply-templates  />
   <xsl:template match="TT">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(../../../../../@id,$tab,../../../../../@desc,$tab)"  /> <!-- Brand -->
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(../../../../@id,$tab,../../../../@desc,$tab)"  /> <!-- Type -->
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(../../../@id,$tab,../../../@desc,$tab)"  /> <!-- Product -->
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(../../@id,$tab,../../@desc,$tab)"  /> <!-- Series -->
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(../@id,$tab,../@desc,$tab)"     /> <!-- Model -->
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($tab, $tab, $tab, $tab, $tab,    $tab)" />  <!-- Region -->
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(@code, $tab, @desc, $tab, @colCode)" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It show only the TT but not the Region.

How can I correct this XSLT?

Comment: Did you try something on your own? Can you post your XSLT?

Comment: This is confusing: you say you want a CSV file, but you are attempting to build a tab-separated one - and the output that you show is neither.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do (which is not at all certain), you should try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="ISO-8859-1" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space  elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#x0A;'" />
<xsl:variable name="tab" select="'&#x09;'" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Brand/Type/Product/Series/Model/Region">
        <xsl:variable name="common" select="concat(ancestor::Brand/@id, $tab, ancestor::Type/@id, $tab, ancestor::Product/@id, $tab, ancestor::Series/@id, $tab, ancestor::Model/@id, $tab, @id)"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="../TT">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($common, $tab, @code, $newline)" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example (after closing the `Brand` tag properly!), the result will be:

```
1   1   1   10496   10497   4   696033805
1   1   1   10496   10497   4   696033808
1   1   1   10496   10497   4   696044567
1   1   1   10496   10497   1   696033805
1   1   1   10496   10497   1   696033808
1   1   1   10496   10497   1   696044567
```

---

### Edit

> i have find that i have another case, i can have Model with region and
>   TT and Model with only TT

That's quite a difference, and it requires a significant change in the approach:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="ISO-8859-1" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space  elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#x0A;'" />
<xsl:variable name="tab" select="'&#x09;'" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Brand/Type/Product/Series/Model">
        <xsl:variable name="common" select="concat(ancestor::Brand/@id, $tab, ancestor::Type/@id, $tab, ancestor::Product/@id, $tab, ancestor::Series/@id, $tab, ancestor::Model/@id, $tab, @id)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Region">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Region">
                    <xsl:with-param name="common" select="$common"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="TT">
                    <xsl:with-param name="common" select="concat($common, $tab)" />
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Region"> 
    <xsl:param name="common"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="../TT">
        <xsl:with-param name="common" select="concat($common, $tab, @id)" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="TT"> 
    <xsl:param name="common"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($common, $tab, @code, $newline)" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
1   1   1   10496       10497   4   696033805
1   1   1   10496       10497   4   696033808
1   1   1   10496       10497   4   696044567
1   1   1   10496       10497   1   696033805
1   1   1   10496       10497   1   696033808
1   1   1   10496       10497   1   696044567
1   1   1   10496       11597       123033805
1   1   1   10496       11597       234033808
```

Comment: Thanks very much, i have correct the code, but i have find that i have another case, i can have Model with region and TT and Model with only TT, your code don't show this second case.

Comment: @StefanoCalciati "*your code don't show this second case.*". Of course it doesn't. I am not clairvoyant. And it makes a big difference: I don't think there is an elegant way to treat both cases with the same code. You need to branch at the Model level.